# Loop de artículos en Javascript desde un JSON

Tags: javascript, html5, json

Quiero hacer un loop en Javascript para mostrar una lista de artículos de un JSON que tengo localmente y poder luego ver los detalles de cada artículo en una página diferente o en un modal de boostrap. Como si fuera un blog

Tiene que ser todo del lado del cliente pues es para hacer una app con Phonegap la que compila solo archivos locales imposibilitado el uso de Angular, Vue o cualquier Framework por el Estilo.

Al final mi idea es enviar las actualizaciones de mi blog por correo electrónico en un JSON pues para mis lectores en Cuba les sería de bendición porque acá no tenemos mucho acceso al Internet.

He intentado de varias formas pero mi novatada me supera y no logro avanzar...

```js
var posts = [{
  "titulo": "Mi primera entrada",
  "id": "1",
  "autor": "Yamy",
  "link": "www.maranatacuba.org",
  "contenido": "Este es un ejemplo de texto que voy a repetir por gusto para llenar espacio1111111111"
},
{
  "titulo": "Mi Segunda Entrada",
  "autor": "Royler",
  "id": "2",
  "contenido": "Este es un ejemplo de texto que voy a repetir por gusto para llenar espacio 2",
  "link": "www.maranatacuba.orgggg"
},
{
  "titulo": "Mi Tercera entrada entrada",
  "id": "3",
  "link": "www.maranatacuba.org",
  "autor": "Sonia",
  "contenido": "Este es un ejemplo de texto que voy a repetir por gusto para llenar espacio"
}
];

var lista = document.getElementById('listadearticulos');
var detalles = document.getElementById('detalles');

for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {

  var articulo = document.createElement('article');
  var id = document.createElement('h6');
  var titulo = document.createElement('h2');
  var boton = document.createElement('div');
  var contenido = document.createElement('p');

  contenido.innerHTML = '<p style = "display:none;" > ' + posts[i].contenido + '</p > '
  boton.innerHTML = '<button class="btn verMassuccess" onclick="verdetalles(); " type="button" id = "verMas" > ' + 'Leer' + '</button > ';
  id.innerHTML = '<h3 class="oculto" id="11">' + posts[i].id + '</h3>';
  titulo.innerHTML = '<h3 class="btnTitulo">' + '<a ' + ' href=' + '>' + posts[i].titulo + '</a>' + '</h3>';

  articulo.appendChild(titulo);
  articulo.appendChild(boton);
  articulo.appendChild(contenido);

  lista.appendChild(articulo);

  function verdetalles() {
    $('.verMas').click(function () {
      $('#detalles2').empty();
      $('#11').appendTo('#detalles2');
    });

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header">
</header>
<div class="container-fluid bg-warning text-center">Prueba</div>
<section><div id="listadearticulos"></div></section>
<div id="detalles"></div>
```

Comment: los `id` deben ser únicos para cada elemento del DOM. Por otro lado estás haciendo target a un elemento con el id `detalles2` que no aparece en tu código.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const MIS_ARTICULOS = [{
  "titulo" : "Mi primera entrada",
  "id" : "1",
   "autor" : "Yamy",
   "link" : "www.maranatacuba.org",
   "contenido" : "Este es un ejemplo de texto que voy a repetir por gusto para llenar espacio1111111111" 
   },
   {
   "titulo" : "Mi Segunda Entrada",
    "autor" : "Royler",
     "id" : "2",
    "contenido" : "Este es un ejemplo de texto que voy a repetir por gusto para llenar espacio 2",
    "link" : "www.maranatacuba.orgggg"
      },
     {
      "titulo" : "Mi Tercera entrada entrada",
      "id" : "3",
       "link" : "www.maranatacuba.org",
       "autor" : "Sonia",
      "contenido" : "Este es un ejemplo de texto que voy a  repetir por gusto para llenar espacio" 
       }
       ];

// Iteración de los ARTICULOS.
var vistaArticulos ='';
for ( var articulo of MIS_ARTICULOS ) {
   const panel = document.createElement('div');
   panel.id = articulo.id;
   panel.classList.add('panel');
   const panelHeader = document.createElement('div');
   panelHeader.classList.add('panel-heading');
   const panelBody = document.createElement('div');
   panelBody.classList.add('panel-body');
   const title = document.createElement('h4');
   title.innerText = articulo.titulo;
   panelHeader.appendChild(title);
 const autor = document.createElement('strong');
   autor.innerText = articulo.autor;
   const enlace = document.createElement('a');
   enlace.href = articulo.link;
   enlace.innerText= 'Más información !';
   enlace.target = '_blank';
   const contenido = document.createElement('p');
   contenido.innerText = articulo.contenido;
   panelBody.appendChild(autor);
   panelBody.appendChild(contenido);
   panelBody.appendChild(enlace);
   panel.appendChild(panelHeader);
   panel.appendChild(panelBody);
   vistaArticulos +=  panel.outerHTML;
}

document.getElementById('MODAL_BODY_ID').innerHTML = vistaArticulos;
```

```html
<div id="MODAL_BODY_ID">
  <!-- NO ES UN MODAL, PERO REPRESENTA EL ACCESO MEDIANTE ID A SU BODY -->
</div>
```

Comment: Joel, muchas gracias..!!!

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido, sí la puedes dar como valida la respuesta para cerrar la pregunta, genial Sr.Royler =)

Comment: Joel. Ya implementé lo que me diste y me funciona. Lista los tres "articulos" de mi JSON.. Pero lo que necesito es que cuando le dé click en Más Información me cargue otra vista con el mismo contenido de ese artículo, no que me abra otra pestaña con el link para verlo online. Pues la idea es enviar los artículos en un JSON por correo y que en el home de la aplicación se vea la lista y cuando se clicke cualquiera de estos se vea el contenido completo.

Comment: Es decir, a partir del enlace en el JSON, que abra la información de autor y contenido en un modal ??

Comment: En un modal o en otra página